# Table head getting orphaned when printing (wkhtmltopdf) page with multiple tables

Tags: html, css, printing, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

My application generates an HTML page with multiple tables.
I convert this HTML page to pdf with wkhtmltopdf.

I use `<thead>` so that table headings repeat on every page when tables are split across multiple pages.

If there is enough space at the end of the page to render the `<thead>`, it gets rendered - even if there is not enough space to render the first row of the table. The result is that some pages have only a "orphaned" `<thead>` at the bottom of the page.

The `<thead>` gets rendered normally again on the next page followed by the remaining table rows.

I am not sure if this is an issue with webkit, or wkhtmltopdf.

I have read everything I could find, and I have tried everything I can think of.

`page-break-after: avoid;` does not work with  as it is not a block level element - if I make it a block it breaks the table.

I can't use `page-break-inside: avoid;` on the table because I need the tables to split across pages.

I have also tried `thead:after {content: '', display: block, page-break-after: avoid;}` No luck.

I would really appreciate any help - I am completely stuck.

Note: I realise there are many page breaking issues across browsers - I only need this to work with wkhtmltopdf (webkit).

Comment: Still an issue.  :(